# Java partial unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have used [this example of partial-unmarshalling](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=litle-sdk-for-java/lib/jaxb/samples/partial-unmarshalling/src/Main.java) to to unmarshall an XML to object:

The issue is that I want to unmarshal only part of the elements to objects -  with some exceptions. So I need to get values from other parts, for example:

```xml
<xml>                                   
  <schools>
    <school>Prinston</school>
    <address>road town 12</address>
    <student id = “11235813”>
        <name>Jayaraman</name>
    </student>
    <student id = “21345589”>
        <name>Shyam</name>
    </student>
    <student id = “21345589”>
        <name>Shyam</name>
    </student>
    <total_students>Prinston</total_students>
  </schools>
</xml>
```

Currently I am using a splitter to convert the `student`s into a class. But while I do it, I want to get the school `name`, `address` and so on...
How can I do it?
Maybe using different approach?